# Bootstrap uncollapsed panel by default

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a collapsable panel but I want it to be uncollapsed by default.

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-collapse-down"> </span>1st Round</a>
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">First round details</div>

    </div>
</div>
```

If I remove **collapse** from

```
<div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
```

It works, but the first time clicked to uncollapse doesn't work.

Comment: Clicking on the panel in jquery document ready function can also expand the panel by default like $(".panel-title").click();

Answer (score 152, accepted):

In Bootstrap 3.x, add a class "in" to your collapsable div

```
<div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
```

It will keep your div open by default.

**Update:**

With Bootstrap 4.0, You need to add `show` class in place of `in`.

Comment: @aliawadh980 you should post that as an answer, or Kamlesh should update the answer.

Comment: The `collapsing` class is only applied in 4.x while transitioning. The right class is `collapse`

Comment: For BS 3 u r right. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/javascript/#collapse-example makes no mention of the `in`. Life saver.

Comment: Updated answer for Bootstrap 4.0 was a big time saver.

Comment: For React Bootstrap 4 Accordion, you can use:  <Accordion defaultActiveKey="0"> to set a specific accordion to be un-collapsed on load.

Answer (score 14):

With Boostrap 4, simply add the class `show` to show the collapsed content on page load:

```
<div class="collapse show">...</div>
```

As per [Bootstrap 4 documention](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/):

- `.collapse` hides content
- `.collapse.show` shows content

Answer (score 3):

Add a class `in` to the panel with  id `collapse1` like below

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-collapse-down"> </span>1st Round</a>
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <div class="panel-body">First round details</div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="collapse in show" id="collapseExample">
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use some js to remove the class on window load

```
$(window).load(function() {
     $("#collapse1").removeClass("collapse");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add [closeOthers]="true" under accordion
and [isOpen]="true"       under accordion group